# AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'get_all_emojis'

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

```
from distutils.util import change_root
from discord.utils import get
import discord
import random
import shutil

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = client.get_channel(968268255804420096)
    emoji = await discord.utils.get(client.get_all_emojis(), name='upvote')
    await client.add_reaction(message, emoji)
```

i'm trying to make a bot react to all messages in a specific channel, but i keep getting the "AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'get_all_emojis'" error
any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This no longer works because `get_all_emojis` was [removed a long time ago](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating_to_v1.html?highlight=get_all_emojis#models-are-stateful). Instead, use [`client.emojis`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.emojis).

```py
emoji = discord.utils.get(client.emojis, name='upvote')
```

Comment: since when discord.utils.get is a coroutine?

Comment: It is not, maybe this was written during the old times before 1.0. I fixed it